# SWI-Prolog YALL conflict with dicts

Tags: dictionary, prolog, swi-prolog

SWI-Prolog version 8.0.3 for x64-win64, using `yall` for lambdas.  (`use_module(library(yall)).`)

Trying to access a value in a dict, within a labmda, causes an error.
I think this is less a problem with `yall`, and more a problem with dicts in...let's call them "goal-as-value"s, because I'm not sure of the correct term.  (For example, `X = (Y = 1)`.)  An example representative of my actual problem would be `?- L = [S]>>(S=a{x:_},S.x = 10).`, but I'll give a simpler example to start.

Consider:

```
?- L = (S=a{x:_},S.x = 10).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(instantiation_error,_11412))
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

when I would instead expect something like the following:

```
?- L = (S=a{x:_},S.x = 10).
L =  (S=a{x:_14168}, S.x=10).
```

Going back to lambdas, note that my intent *can* be accomplished, with e.g.

```
?- L = [S]>>(S=a{x:_},(.(S,x,10))).
L = [S]>>(S=a{x:_8692}, '.'(S, x, 10)).
```

It's just kinda horrible.
(Calling this lambda yields `S = a{x:10}`, as expected.)

This seems like a bug in SWI-Prolog, or at least an undocumented limitation.  Have I missed something, or should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

As your `L = (S=a{x:_},S.x = 10)` query shows, the error have nothing to do with `library(yall)` but with dicts semantics. When using **functional notation**, as in `S.x = 10`, SWI-Prolog performs **eager evaluation** of `S.x` during query **compilation**, i.e. **before** the `S=a{x:_}` goal is proved. Hence the instantiation error. As you found, not using functional notation by switching to the `'.'(S, x, 10)` goal solves the problem as it becomes the second goal being proved on the conjunction.

Comment: This seems like a bug in SWI-Prolog, or at least an undocumented limitation. Have I missed something, or should I file a bug report?